# asp.net two applications on one domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm developing webpage with asp.net hosted on IIS and client requested to rework it so I made second application, then client said even though we only have homepage reworked it must go live, and that created a problem we have domain lets say www.example.com and we need to make rewrite from www.example.com/homepage to our second application and the rest routing must stay the same. Is it possible to make rewrites between two applications? What do I need to configure to achive that?

I'm using IIRF for redirects and rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

It would be fairly easy to write an URL Rewrite  (inbound rule) for this.

this article should give you everything you need...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

before that you need to configure the app1 and app2 directories in the inetpub/wwwroot directory, and configure both of them as applications, it should have the effect you desire. then apply url rewrite to main app

Comment: That's a typical way of using rewrites within one application - in my case I have two separate applications (as far as I don't know how and if it is possible to bond them together). I don't think I'm able to make rewrite for example from : www.example.com to www.msdn.com (that would not be cool if site could pretend to be any other site - and i guess that is my case). I need a way to somehow bond two applications together.

Comment: This is achieved on same domain, without going to 2 domains.... you have to configure the app1 and app2 directories in the inetpub/wwwroot directory, and configure both of them as applications, it should have the effect you desire. then apply url rewrite to main app

Comment: @Rozrzutnik  you followed what i mentioned here?